# How to send data to a REST API every minute from android using kotlin?

Tags: android, rest, android-service, wear-os, android-service-binding

Assuming that I have implemented a SensorEventListener from which I generate the values deriving from the movement of the accelerometer of the device; that I have implemented the visualization in the UI of the heartbeat using the documentation and the example "Measure Data"; that I have already implemented a service that extends the SensorEventListener interface.

I would like to combine these two data into a single request (possibly from the same service) sent every minute to a REST API.

This, however, I can not make it work because every time the screen on the device turns off after less than a few seconds I no longer receive the data in the console from the service with the Listener (I have not yet combined the two data, in fact I am also trying to understand how bring the part of the MeasureClient to the service).

Comment: Most of the restrictions in background tasks are there to stop exactly this sort of app behaviour which would drain the battery. Do you really need to send data minutely, or could you collect in batches and send periodically?

Comment: Yes I'm sure if this. It is an application that must constantly send data for medical purposes.